# How can I write dynamic SQL Statements?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a complex logic in mind, I have an effective date from which I want to find out end date, for example for particular company A1 if second row contains eff_date as 2016-08-21 and latest eff_date is 2017-08-21 then end date for second row should be -1 day that is 2017-08-20, and the end date for 2017-08-21 will be of today date whatever it will be, and this should work for all the other companies.

After this I want to find out the difference of these date that is, of my eff_date is 2016-08-21 and end date is 2017-08-20, then I would like to know what are all the dates that lies between eff_date and end_date, is there any way to right the queries in such a way so that I should get updated results?

Comment: You need to post what you have tried if anything. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, perhaps use a CTE?

Comment: You don't seem to be needing dynamic SQL at all. Dynamic SQL is when the ordinary SQL syntax doesn't cover you and you instead make queries that generate code of other queries. You only need some date logic, maybe some queries between, and a numbers table solution for finding a date range. If you make your examples *much* clearer by providing sample data and expected results, you will probably get an answer.

Comment: Dynamic SQL Statements *normally* means that you have an object that needs to change depending on the query, a pivot for an indeterminable number of values, or parametrisation of a query that cannot normally be (such as `OPENQUERY`). Your description doesn't infer any of these, so I doubt you need a dynamic statement.

Comment: Any explanation or any sort of example will greatly help me on this.